# Error #1006: descendre is not a function at main/loop()

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make my character move with the keyboard arrows in AS3. And I got the error:

```
Error #1006: descendre is not a function at main/loop()
```

Here is my code:

In `main.as`:

```
    private function down(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (e.keyCode==_LEFT) {
            gauche=true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==_UP) {
            haut=true;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==_DOWN) {
            bas=true;
            trace("down")
        }
        if (e.keyCode==_RIGHT) {
            droit=true;
        }
    }//down
    private function up(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if (e.keyCode==_LEFT) {
            gauche=false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==_UP) {
            haut=false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==_DOWN) {
            bas=false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==_RIGHT) {
            droit=false;
        }
    }//up
    private function loop(e:Event):void{;
        if (haut) {
            vache_mc.monter();
        }
        if (bas) {
            vache_mc.descendre();
        }
        if (droit) {
            vache_mc.coted();
        }
        if (gauche) {
            vache_mc.coteg();
        }
    }//loop
```

in `vache.as`:

```
    private function monter():void {
        trace("monter");
    }//monter
    private function descendre():void {
        trace("descendre");
    }//descendre
    private function coted():void {
        trace("coted");
    }//coted
    private function coteg():void {
        trace("coteg");
    }//coteg
```

My character instance name is `vache_mc` and it is already on stage.

Thank you for helping me :)

(I'm french that's why variable names are quite strange and my English poor)

Answer (score 2):

Your movement methods in vache.as need to be `public` instead of `private` if they will be called from main.as. I think you also need to make sure vache.as is actually set as the class of vache_mc.

Comment: >.< thank you!! your were right... i forgot to link vache_mc to vache.as (shame on me!!)